# Image classification

Tags: python, deep-learning, image-classification

I was recently working on a project that classifies images and i was trying to **import images** into my notebook as **Input**. i've tried every way and the only way that worked is to import each image as an array and i'm not sure that my model will work correctly in this case. Here is my code, can anyone help me please.

```
import matplotlib.image as img
import glob
pic_dir = r'C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\imcancer'
pic_files = glob.glob("%s/*.jpg" % pic_dir)
images = []
i=0
for file in pic_files:
    i+=1
    data = img.imread(file)
    images.append(data) # charger les images dans une liste
print('total number of images = ',i)
```

Comment: Can you clarify: What is "every way" you have tried? What is the result you wish to see? An array is just a representation of data. Every image is in way just an array or a collection of arrays, so the data being an array is not in itself a problem. Please provide a code snippet that someone else could run on their machine! E.g what libraries is referenced in "img.imread(file)"?

Comment: This might depend on *how you are doing classification*.  Keras and PyTorch each have intro tutorials on image classification, and each have a step that shows roughly what you are doing here ([Keras Image Classification](https://keras.io/examples/vision/image_classification_from_scratch/), [PyTorch Image Classification](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with Ml models and images, you would require to convert them into numbers (arrays for precision) either way in order to process them since Ml models can only work with numbers. So if you need to process them with a neural network is completely fine to do what you are doing.

Comment: thank you a lot for answering me, I was really confused.